# Monitoring clients IP Address in realtime with meteor

Tags: meteor, ip, userid

I have a Meteor app, which should only work for some white listed IP Addresses (EDIT: User can have different IP white lists). So if a logged in user leaves an IP (for example he switches to 3G on his mobile) I want him to log out automagically. 
I know that within a Meteor method, this.connection, and this.userId gives me enough information to accomplish this. But I dont want to check for each method call the user restrictions. The OnConnection callback could be here of use. But inside it, i have no user information. What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is probably much easier to do via nginx. There are Meteor and npm packages available [simonrycroft:ip-whitelist](https://atmospherejs.com/simonrycroft/ip-whitelist) and [express-ipfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But in my case, each user can have a different IP white list. So I have to monitor the IP per user.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfull use this package: `mizzao:user-status` to ensure only a user per account. Maybe you should give it a look.